# Downloading data table from a website requires login in R

Tags: r, jsp, web-scraping

I am trying to automate downloading data from a website which requires login first. After login, I need to select the particular table that I want to download from a dropdown and then select the dates for which I want the data and then download it into text format. Can this be done in R? The page I m trying to scrape is a jsp page and when I run the following command it gives me an error like "JSP processing error". Can anybody help me with the solution? ALso, I need to select the dates, so need to get those forms also.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
handle <- handle("http://xyzwebsite.jsp") 

# fields found in the login form.
login <- list(
   ussername = "username"
  ,password  = "password"
)

response <- POST(handle = handle, body = login)
response
```

Comment: Is the parameter indeed called `ussername` (note the double s)?

Comment: Sounds like `RSelenium`.

Comment: Thanks...No that would be username. With Rselenium would I be able to select from a dropdown or would I be able to select a specific tie period?